# grep show output, then do something with it

Tags: linux, search, sed, grep, pipe

I try to use script for find messages in mail server. I need to see file location and output. then i do

```
grep -r KTsiPtCf0YDQvtC00LDQstC10YYt0LrQvtC90YHRg9C70YzRgtCw0L3RgiDRgdCw0LvQ ./aaa/Maildir/cur/
```

output is

```
./aaa/Maildir/cur/1506410272.M30769P16754.ml.exmp.com,S=134882,W=136851:2,S:KTsiPtCf0YDQvtC00LDQstC10YYt0LrQvtC90YHRg9C70YzRgtCw0L3RgiDRgdCw0LvQ
```

And then, i need to cut all before ":"  and make search result readable.

```
 grep -r KTsiPtCf0YDQvtC00LDQstC10YYt0LrQvtC90YHRg9C70YzRgtCw0L3RgiDRgdCw0LvQ ./aaa/Maildir/cur/  | sed 's/.*://' |base64 -d|  enca -L ru -x utf-8
```

But if i do it by pipe i miss file location. How to output location of file and then do pipe?

Comment: After file name in `grep` output there should be a colon `:`. Yours is a comma. Is that right?

Comment: no, filename is ./aaa/Maildir/cur/1506410272.M30769P16754.ml.exmp.com,S=134882,W=136851:2,S

Comment: So what you are trying to remove?

Comment: i try to remove file location, to decode only text, that i found. but location of file is also need

Comment: so i want to see in output: FILELOCATION and DECODED text under or near it

Comment: Your question is unclear, but perhaps you want `sed 's/,.*//'`

Comment: Im already do this   `grep -r codedtext ./aaa/Maildir/cur/file  | sed 's/.*://' |base64 -d|  enca -L ru -x utf-8`. Output is folder location before colon `:` `./aaa/Maildir/cur/1506410272.M30769P16754.ml.exmp.com,S=134882,W=136851:2,S`: and after colon `:` i have coded text `KTsiPtCf0YDQvtC00LDQstC10YYt0LrQvtC90YHRg9C70YzRgtCw0L3RgiDRgdCw0LvQ`. I need to output file location and decode text after `:` Like `./aaa/Maildir/cur/filelocation:decodedtext`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.